# Using findText to find colons

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I am using this code in Google Docs

```html
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

  var foundElement = body.findText(": ");
  while (foundElement != null) {
    // Get the text object from the element
    var foundText = foundElement.getElement().asText();

    // Where in the Element is the found text?
    var start = foundElement.getStartOffset();
    var end = foundElement.getEndOffsetInclusive();

    // Change the background color to yellow
    foundText.setBackgroundColor('#42e2f4');

    // Find the next match
    foundElement = body.findText(": ", foundElement);
    }
```

To find all ": " and underline them. But the script underlines the entire line. Why? Is it due to the fact that ":" is not properly "text"? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

In your script, `start` and `end` of offset are not used. So how about this modification?

#### From:

```
foundText.setBackgroundColor('#42e2f4');
```

#### To:

```
foundText.setBackgroundColor(start, end, '#42e2f4');
```

#### References:

- [setForegroundColor(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setforegroundcolorstartoffset-endoffsetinclusive-color)